# In webflux, What is the difference between WebFilter and HandlerFilterFunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

In spring webflux, What is the difference between `WebFilter` and   `HandlerFilterFunction` ?

And how i can create a `filter` that is used for a certain `URI` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference between them is that `WebFilter` implementations work for all endpoints and `HandlerFilterFunction` implementations will only work for Router-based ones.

So if you use `Router` based endpoints you can use either of them. But if you use annotation based (like `@RequestMapping`/`@GetMapping`) you can only make use of `WebFilter`.